# ESP32 Multiple Connections via Bluetooth Low Energy

Tags: bluetooth, bluetooth-lowenergy, esp32

I use the following code to switch two relays with the smartphone on an ESP32 via BLE. The code works so far, but I can only connect one smartphone to the ESP32, as soon as it is connected, the ESP32 is no longer visible to other smartphones - only when I disconnect the first smartphone, the ESP32 is visible again and another smartphone can reconnect.

Therefore I have the following questions:

1. Can several smartphones connect to the ESP32 via Bluetooth at the same time?
2. If not, could the connection to the previous smartphone be interrupted as soon as a new one wants to connect to the ESP32?

Here is my current code:

```
#include <BLEDevice.h>
#include <BLEServer.h>
#include <BLEUtils.h>
#include <BLE2902.h>

// Relais-Pins
const int relay1Pin = 18; // GPIO 18
const int relay2Pin = 19; // GPIO 19

BLEServer *pServer = NULL;
BLECharacteristic *pCharacteristic = NULL;
bool relay1State = false;
bool relay2State = false;

class MyServerCallbacks : public BLEServerCallbacks {
  void onConnect(BLEServer *pServer) {
    // Handle connection
  }

  void onDisconnect(BLEServer *pServer) {
    // Handle disconnection
    BLEDevice::startAdvertising(); // Start advertising to allow reconnection
  }
};

class MyCallbacks : public BLECharacteristicCallbacks {
  void onWrite(BLECharacteristic *pCharacteristic) {
    std::string value = pCharacteristic->getValue();

    if (value.length() > 0) {
      if (value[0] == '1') {
        digitalWrite(relay1Pin, true);
        delay(500);
        digitalWrite(relay1Pin, false);
      } else if (value[0] == '2') {
        digitalWrite(relay2Pin, true);
        delay(500);
        digitalWrite(relay2Pin, false);
      }
    }
  }
};

void setup() {
  pinMode(relay1Pin, OUTPUT);
  pinMode(relay2Pin, OUTPUT);
  digitalWrite(relay1Pin, relay1State);
  digitalWrite(relay2Pin, relay2State);

  BLEDevice::init("ESP32_Relay_Control");
  pServer = BLEDevice::createServer();
  pServer->setCallbacks(new MyServerCallbacks());

  BLEService *pService = pServer->createService(BLEUUID("0000FFFF-0000-1000-8000-00805F9B34FB"));

  pCharacteristic = pService->createCharacteristic(
      BLEUUID("0000FF01-0000-1000-8000-00805F9B34FB"),
      BLECharacteristic::PROPERTY_READ | BLECharacteristic::PROPERTY_WRITE
  );

  pCharacteristic->setCallbacks(new MyCallbacks());

  pService->start();

  BLEAdvertising *pAdvertising = BLEDevice::getAdvertising();
  pAdvertising->addServiceUUID(pService->getUUID());
  pAdvertising->start();
}

void loop() {
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Advertising stops automatically when a central connects.

Currently, you start advertising again only on disconnect (onDisconnect). You can start advertising again on connect instead. Then you should be able to get multiple connections. Just make sure you handle the case when maximum connections are reached.